# How To drag an image object in WxPython GUI?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, wxpython

In below code, I have image shaped transparent window and a image inside of it, I would like to move the image(screw photo)by mouse. I wrote a bind function for that screw image but it does not move? what might be the problem?

As it can be seen I added images and bind functions. Is there a missing logic?

```
 import wx
from wx import *
import wx.lib.statbmp as sb
from io import StringIO


# Create a .png image with something drawn on a white background
# and put the path to it here.
IMAGE_PATH = './wood.png'


class ShapedFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "Shaped Window",
            style = wx.FRAME_SHAPED | wx.SIMPLE_BORDER | wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
        self.hasShape = False
        self.delta = wx.Point(0,0)

        # Load the image
        image = wx.Image(IMAGE_PATH, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
        image.SetMaskColour(255,255,255)
        image.SetMask(True)            
        self.bmp = wx.Bitmap(image)

        self.SetClientSize((self.bmp.GetWidth(), self.bmp.GetHeight()))
        dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.bmp, 0,0, True)
        self.SetWindowShape()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_UP, self.OnExit)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_WINDOW_CREATE, self.SetWindowShape)

        panel = MyPanel(parent=self)

    def SetWindowShape(self, evt=None):
        r = wx.Region(self.bmp)
        self.hasShape = self.SetShape(r)

    def OnDoubleClick(self, evt):
        if self.hasShape:
            self.SetShape(wx.Region())
            self.hasShape = False
        else:
            self.SetWindowShape()

    def OnPaint(self, evt):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.bmp, 0,0, True)

    def OnExit(self, evt):
        self.Close()

    def OnLeftDown(self, evt):
        self.CaptureMouse()
        pos = self.ClientToScreen(evt.GetPosition())
        origin = self.GetPosition()
        self.delta = wx.Point(pos.x - origin.x, pos.y - origin.y)

    def OnMouseMove(self, evt):
        if evt.Dragging() and evt.LeftIsDown():
            pos = self.ClientToScreen(evt.GetPosition())
            newPos = (pos.x - self.delta.x, pos.y - self.delta.y)
            self.Move(newPos)

    def OnLeftUp(self, evt):
        if self.HasCapture():
            self.ReleaseMouse()



class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    # A panel is a window on which controls are placed. (e.g. buttons and text boxes)
    # wx.Panel class is usually put inside a wxFrame object. This class is also inherited from wxWindow class.
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        MyImage(self)



class MyImage(wx.StaticBitmap):

    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        
        jpg1 = wx.Image('./Images/screwsmall.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        # bitmap upper left corner is in the position tuple (x, y) = (5, 5)
        self.myImage = wx.StaticBitmap(parent, -1, jpg1, (10 + jpg1.GetWidth(), 5), (jpg1.GetWidth(), jpg1.GetHeight()))
        self.myImage.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMouseMove)
        self.myImage.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnLeftDown)

    def OnMouseMove(self, evt):
        if evt.Dragging() and evt.LeftIsDown():
            pos = self.ClientToScreen(evt.GetPosition())
            newPos = (pos.x - self.delta.x, pos.y - self.delta.y)
            self.Move(newPos)

    def OnLeftUp(self, evt):
        if self.HasCapture():
            self.ReleaseMouse()

    def OnLeftDown(self, evt):
        self.CaptureMouse()
        pos = self.ClientToScreen(evt.GetPosition())
        origin = self.GetPosition()
        self.delta = wx.Point(pos.x - origin.x, pos.y - origin.y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()

    ShapedFrame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Visual output of my code you can use different shapes in local directory. To install wxpython for 3.x you can check this link https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-16.04/ download your version for ubuntu and use pip install command.

[image]

Comment: Look for a demonstration program called `DragImage.py` in the demos package. https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/4.1.0/wxPython-demo-4.1.0.tar.gz and beware using `CaptureMouse` it can appear to lock your code.

Comment: I already saw that code. it is not easy to run that, dependency to "run" etc. And It was really long. Dragging process is Maximum of 10 line code, and in that splited as a long unnecessary code. Is there a simple way? If not, I will start to look at it. @RolfofSaxony

Comment: If there is a faster way, And it would be a good and simpler guide to the people who see this question. @RolfofSaxony

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Hi my friend I used that code in my own project. It is working Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to put my answer. As it can be seen in the @RolfofSaxony comment, there is a drag image demo inside the WXPYTHON tar file. In that DragImage.py file there are two different classes do the dragging job. I modified those functions and wrote my own two class. You can use these classes in your code as a component. My code is working and tested.

```
class DragShape:
    def __init__(self, bmp):
        self.bmp = bmp
        self.pos = (0,0)
        self.shown = True
        self.text = None
        self.fullscreen = False

    def HitTest(self, pt):
        rect = self.GetRect()
        return rect.Contains(pt)

    def GetRect(self):
        return wx.Rect(self.pos[0], self.pos[1],
                      self.bmp.GetWidth(), self.bmp.GetHeight())

    def Draw(self, dc, op = wx.COPY):
        if self.bmp.IsOk():
            memDC = wx.MemoryDC()
            memDC.SelectObject(self.bmp)

            dc.Blit(self.pos[0], self.pos[1],
                    self.bmp.GetWidth(), self.bmp.GetHeight(),
                    memDC, 0, 0, op, True)

            return True
        else:
            return False



#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class DragCanvas(wx.ScrolledWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID):
        wx.ScrolledWindow.__init__(self, parent, ID)
        self.shapes = []
        self.dragImage = None
        self.dragShape = None
        self.hiliteShape = None

        self.SetCursor(wx.Cursor(wx.CURSOR_ARROW))

        bmp = images.TheKid.GetBitmap()
        shape = DragShape(bmp)
        shape.pos = (200, 5)
        self.shapes.append(shape)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnLeftDown)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnLeftUp)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMotion)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW, self.OnLeaveWindow)


    # We're not doing anything here, but you might have reason to.
    # for example, if you were dragging something, you might elect to
    # 'drop it' when the cursor left the window.
    def OnLeaveWindow(self, evt):
        pass




    # Go through our list of shapes and draw them in whatever place they are.
    def DrawShapes(self, dc):
        for shape in self.shapes:
            if shape.shown:
                shape.Draw(dc)

    # This is actually a sophisticated 'hit test', but in this
    # case we're also determining which shape, if any, was 'hit'.
    def FindShape(self, pt):
        for shape in self.shapes:
            if shape.HitTest(pt):
                return shape
        return None


    # Fired whenever a paint event occurs
    def OnPaint(self, evt):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        self.PrepareDC(dc)
        self.DrawShapes(dc)
        # print('OnPaint')

    # Left mouse button is down.
    def OnLeftDown(self, evt):
        # Did the mouse go down on one of our shapes?
        shape = self.FindShape(evt.GetPosition())

        # If a shape was 'hit', then set that as the shape we're going to
        # drag around. Get our start position. Dragging has not yet started.
        # That will happen once the mouse moves, OR the mouse is released.
        if shape:
            self.dragShape = shape
            self.dragStartPos = evt.GetPosition()

    # Left mouse button up.
    def OnLeftUp(self, evt):
        if not self.dragImage or not self.dragShape:
            self.dragImage = None
            self.dragShape = None
            return

        # Hide the image, end dragging, and nuke out the drag image.
        self.dragImage.Hide()
        self.dragImage.EndDrag()
        self.dragImage = None

        if self.hiliteShape:
            self.RefreshRect(self.hiliteShape.GetRect())
            self.hiliteShape = None

        # reposition and draw the shape

        # Note by jmg 11/28/03
        # Here's the original:
        #
        # self.dragShape.pos = self.dragShape.pos + evt.GetPosition() - self.dragStartPos
        #
        # So if there are any problems associated with this, use that as
        # a starting place in your investigation. I've tried to simulate the
        # wx.Point __add__ method here -- it won't work for tuples as we
        # have now from the various methods
        #
        # There must be a better way to do this :-)
        #

        self.dragShape.pos = (
            self.dragShape.pos[0] + evt.GetPosition()[0] - self.dragStartPos[0],
            self.dragShape.pos[1] + evt.GetPosition()[1] - self.dragStartPos[1]
            )

        self.dragShape.shown = True
        self.RefreshRect(self.dragShape.GetRect())
        self.dragShape = None


    # The mouse is moving
    def OnMotion(self, evt):
        # Ignore mouse movement if we're not dragging.
        if not self.dragShape or not evt.Dragging() or not evt.LeftIsDown():
            return

        # if we have a shape, but haven't started dragging yet
        if self.dragShape and not self.dragImage:

            # only start the drag after having moved a couple pixels
            tolerance = 2
            pt = evt.GetPosition()
            dx = abs(pt.x - self.dragStartPos.x)
            dy = abs(pt.y - self.dragStartPos.y)
            if dx <= tolerance and dy <= tolerance:
                return

            # refresh the area of the window where the shape was so it
            # will get erased.
            self.dragShape.shown = False
            self.RefreshRect(self.dragShape.GetRect(), True)
            self.Update()

            item = self.dragShape.text if self.dragShape.text else self.dragShape.bmp
            self.dragImage = wx.DragImage(item,
                                         wx.Cursor(wx.CURSOR_HAND))

            hotspot = self.dragStartPos - self.dragShape.pos
            self.dragImage.BeginDrag(hotspot, self, self.dragShape.fullscreen)

            self.dragImage.Move(pt)
            self.dragImage.Show()


        # if we have shape and image then move it, posibly highlighting another shape.
        elif self.dragShape and self.dragImage:
            onShape = self.FindShape(evt.GetPosition())
            unhiliteOld = False
            hiliteNew = False

            # figure out what to hilite and what to unhilite
            if self.hiliteShape:
                if onShape is None or self.hiliteShape is not onShape:
                    unhiliteOld = True

            if onShape and onShape is not self.hiliteShape and onShape.shown:
                hiliteNew = True

            # if needed, hide the drag image so we can update the window
            if unhiliteOld or hiliteNew:
                self.dragImage.Hide()

            if unhiliteOld:
                dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
                self.hiliteShape.Draw(dc)
                self.hiliteShape = None

            if hiliteNew:
                dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
                self.hiliteShape = onShape
                self.hiliteShape.Draw(dc, wx.INVERT)

            # now move it and show it again if needed
            self.dragImage.Move(evt.GetPosition())
            if unhiliteOld or hiliteNew:
                self.dragImage.Show()
```

Comment: Glad to see you got your project working. I would have got around to knocking up some code, eventually but I'm busy fire-fighting my own code at the moment.